# Android OpenCV HoughLinesP Crashing

Tags: java, android, opencv

I m trying to make a simple application to detect line with OpenCV

I based my code on the opencv sample code

I only edited the OnCameraFrame part

here is what I have:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat mRgba;
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        int thresh;
        double min;
        double max;

        Mat lines = new Mat();
        thresh = 50;
        min = 20;
        max = 20;
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mRgba, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, thresh, min, max);
        return mRgba;
    }
```

The application is crashing but

if I remove this line it runs with no problem:

```
Imgproc.HoughLinesP(mRgba, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, thresh, min, max);
```

This is what I m getting when I launch the application:

http://pastebin.com/swGn7ZVJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parametr in this Imgproc function should be (from docs):

> 8-bit, single-channel binary source image.

Your mRgba is 4 channel image (red, green, blue and alpha). Convert it to gray (e.g. inputFrame.gray() ).

Comment: Thank you, its not crashing, but now the window is black, I have no idea why